# Google Apps Script, Propagate comma separated list from google forms list .onlyOnWeekdays() as variable calls

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I have a form that is creating the days of the week that an event may occur on (mon, tue, wed etc) - the output gives the days of the week, comma separated in a single cell on the spreadsheet.

I have then called that cell to an apps script. What I need to do is put the contents of the list in .onlyOnWeekdays so that the google calendar entry that is being created only occurs on the appropriate weekdays.

Every time I try to put a list in remotely, I get Cannot convert Array to Weekday[].

Here is the code

```
    function Export_Techs_to_Calendar() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 500;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 24);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("- Performance Venue Staffing")[0];
  var startDateAndTime = 'Sat Aug 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)';
  var endDateAndTime = 'Wed Aug 31 2017 23:59:59 GMT+0100 (BST)';
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(startDateAndTime), new Date(endDateAndTime));
  var mon = CalendarApp.Weekday.MONDAY;
  var tue = CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY;
  var wed = CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY;
  var thur = CalendarApp.Weekday.THURSDAY;
  var fri = CalendarApp.Weekday.FRIDAY;
  var sat = CalendarApp.Weekday.SATURDAY;
  var sun = CalendarApp.Weekday.SUNDAY;

  //Delete Calendar Events
  for (var i=0; i<events.length ;i++){
      events[i].deleteEvent();
  Utilities.sleep(200);   
  }


  //Export Calendar Events day

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var sDate = row[2]; 
    var fDate = row[4];
    var nDays = ((fDate - sDate)/(1000*60*60*24)); 
    var days = row[22];
    var repeat = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekdays([days]).until(new Date(fDate));
    var title = row[10]+" - "+row[6];
    var cancel = row[19];
    var des = "Description: "+row[7]+"\n"+"Organiser: "+row[8]+"\n"+"Course: "+row[9]+"\n"+"Number of Staff: "+row[11]+"\n"+"Staff Assigned: "+row[13];

    if (title == ""){
      title = 0};
    {};
    var loc = row[10];
    var gue = row[8]+", "+row[12];
    if (gue == "-"){gue = ""};


    //multi-day event

    if (((typeof title == 'string') && (sDate != "") && (cancel == "") && (nDays > 1))){ 
    try{
    cal.createAllDayEventSeries(title, new Date(sDate), repeat, {location:loc, description:des, guests:gue, sendInvites:true});
        Utilities.sleep(200);
    }
    catch (e) { 
    cal.createAllDayEventSeries(title, new Date(sDate), repeat, {location:loc, description:des});
      Utilities.sleep(200);
    };

    };    
    {};

  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
var days = row[22];
```

will be returning a single string

```
"mon,tue,wed"
```

You will need to split the string into an array of individual values:

```
var days = row[22];
var daysArray = days.split(",");
```

Which will give you

```
["mon", "tue", "wed"]
```

Now, `daysArray` may be enough to pass in as the argument in your `.onlyOnWeekdays()` method.

If it isn't you'll need to 'build' the argument by looping through `daysArray` and pushing the `CalendarApp.Weekday.WEEKDAY` syntax values to an array and use that instead.

**EDIT**

For this I'd use an object:

```
var weekdaySyntax = {
   mon : "CalendarApp.Weekday.MONDAY",
   tue : "CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY",
   wed : "CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY",
   thu : "CalendarApp.Weekday.THURSDAY",
   fri : "CalendarApp.Weekday.FRIDAY",
}

var output = [];

//assumes daysArray = ["mon", tue", "wed"];
for (i in daysArray) {
  var day = daysArray[i];
  output.push(weekdaySyntax[day]);
};

console.log(output);//Should return ["CalendarApp.Weekday.MONDAY", "CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY", "CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY"]
```

This all assumes that daysArray contains values like ["mon","tue","wed"]? You've not explicitly shown what values you're actually working with so adjust as necessary :)

Additional issue is that the `CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekdays()` method probably doesn't accept an array of strings as its argument? Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Neither worked. I tried the following for code to create the array
    `
        var output = [];
    for (i in daysArray)
    {
      var day = daysArray[i];
      daysOutput = "CalendarApp.Weekday."+day;
    output.push(daysOutput);
    
    };
    `